# How should I write a test for a pure method which doesn't return anything?

Tags: unit-testing, exceptions, readability

I have a bunch of classes which deal with validation of values. For instance, a `RangeValidator` class checks whether a value is within the specified range.

Every validator class contains two methods: `is_valid(value)`, which returns `True` or `False` depending on the value, and `ensure_valid(value)` which checks for a specified value and either does nothing if the value is valid, or throws a specific exception if the value doesn't match the predefined rules.

There are currently two unit tests associated with this method:

- The one which passes an invalid value, and ensures that the exception was thrown.

  ```
  def test_outside_range(self):
      with self.assertRaises(demo.ValidationException):
          demo.RangeValidator(0, 100).ensure_valid(-5)
  ```
- The one which passes a valid value.

  ```
  def test_in_range(self):
      demo.RangeValidator(0, 100).ensure_valid(25)
  ```

Although the second test does its job—fails if the exception is thrown, and succeeds if `ensure_valid` doesn't throw anything—the fact that there is no `assert`s inside looks strange. Someone who reads such code would immediately ask himself why is there a test which *appears* to be doing nothing.

Is this a current practice when testing methods which don't return a value and don't have side effects? Or should I rewrite the test in a different way? Or simply put a comment explaining what I'm doing?

Comment: possibly related: [How to not test implementation when method returns void?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/334580/how-to-not-test-implementation-when-method-returns-void)

Comment: Pedantic point, but if you have a function that takes no arguments (save for a `self` reference) and returns no result, it ain't a pure function.

Comment: @DavidArno: This is not a pedantic point, it goes right to the heart of the question: the method is hard to test precisely *because* it is impure.

Comment: @DavidArno More pedantic point, you could have the "do nothing" method (assuming "returns no results" is interpreted as "returns a unit type" which is called `void` in many languages and has silly rules.) Alternatively, you could have an infinite loop (which works even when "returns no result" *really* means returns no results.

Comment: There is _one_ pure function of type `unit -> unit` in any language which considers unit a standard datatype instead of something magically special-cased. Unfortunately, it just returns unit and does nothing else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most test frameworks have an explicit assertion for "Doesn't throw", e.g. Jasmine has `expect(() => {}).not.toThrow();` and nUnit and friends also have one.

Comment: And if the test framework doesn't have such assertion, it's always possible to create a local method which does exactly the same thing, making the code self-explanatory. Good idea.

Answer (score 7):

This strongly depends on the language and framework used. Speaking in terms of `NUnit`, there are `Assert.Throws(...)` methods. You can pass them a lambda method:

```
Assert.Throws(() => rangeValidator.EnsureValid(-5))
```

which is executed within the `Assert.Throws`. The call to the lambda will most likely be wrapped by a `try { } catch { }` block and the assertion fails, if an exception is caught.

If your framework does not provide these means, you could work it around, by wrapping the call by yourself (I'm writing in C#):

```
// assert that the method does not fail
try
{
    rangeValidator.EnsureValid(50);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(false, $"Exception: {e.Message}");
}

// assert that the method does fail
try
{
    rangeValidator.EnsureValid(50);
    Assert.IsTrue(false, $"Method is expected to throw an exception");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

This makes the intention more clear, but clutters the code to a certain extent. (Of course you can wrap all this stuff in a method.) At the end it will be up to you.

**Edit**

As Doc Brown pointed out in the comments, the issue has not been to indicate that the method throws, but that it does not throw. In NUnit there is also an assertion for that

```
Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => rangeValidator.EnsureValid(-5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a comment to make it clear why no assert is needed and why you didn't forget it.

As you can see in the other answers, anything else makes the code more complicated and cluttered. With the comment there, other programmers will know the intent of the test.

That being said, this kind of test should be an exception (no pun intended). If you find yourself writing something like that regularly, then probably the tests are telling you that the design is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You could also assert that some methods are called (or not called) properly.

For instance:

```
public void SendEmail(User user)
     ... construct email ...
     _emailSender.Send(email);
```

In your test:

```
emailSenderMock.VerifyIgnoreArgs(service =>
    service.Send(It.IsAny<Email>()),
    Times.Once
);
```